# Subset Sum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I am working on this problem:

> The Subset Sum problem takes as input a set `X = {x1, x2 ,…, xn}` of `n` integers and another integer `K`. The problem is to check if there exists a subset `X'` of `X` whose elements sum to `K` and finds the subset if there's any. For example, if `X = {5, 3, 11, 8, 2}` and `K = 16` then the answer is `YES` since the subset `X' = {5, 11}` has a sum of `16`. Implement an algorithm for Subset Sum whose run time is at least `O(nK)`.

Notice complexity `O(nK)`. I think dynamic programming may help.

I have found an exponential time algorithm, but it doesn't help.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I suppose the exercise requests an algorithm which time complexity is *at most* O(nK).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Subset Sum is the first NP-complete problem I learned at Macalester. This question is viewed 36000+ times yet I don't see a sufficient answer that explains the algorithm in detail with logic. So I thought I make an attempt to do so.

**Assumption:**

For the sake of simplicity first I made the assumption that the input set `X` contains only positive integers and `k` is positive. However, we can tweak the algorithm to handle negative integers and the case if `k` is negative.

**Logic:**

The key to this algorithm or really ***any DP problem is to break down the problem and start simply from a base case.*** then we can build on the base case using some knowledge that we know:

1. we know that if the set `X` is empty then there is no way we can sum to any value of `k`.
2. If a set `X` contains `k` then it has a subset sum to `k`.
3. we know that if a subset of set `x1` who is a subset of `X` sum to `k1` then `X` will have a subset that sum to `k1` namely `x1`.
4. we have a set `X = {x1, x1, x3, ......., xn, xn+1}`. We know it has a subset sum to `k1` if `x1 = {x1, x1, x3, ......., xn}` has a subset sum to `k - k1`.

**Example to illustrate 1,2,3,4:**

1. it is easy. if you have an empty set {}. you can't have a subset thus
   you can't have any subset sum.
2. A set `X = {4}` has a subset sum to 4 because 4 it self is part of the set
3. say you have a set `x1 = {1,3,5}` who is a subset of set `X = {1,3,5,2,8}`. if `x1` has a subset sum to `k1 = 8` then that means `X` also has a subset sum to 8 because `x1` is a subset of `X`
4. say you have a set `X = {1,3,5,2,19}` and we want to know does it have a subset sum to 20. It does and one way to can know if that is `x1 = {1,3,5,2}` can sum to (20 - 19) = 1. Since x1 has a subset sum to 1 then when we add 19 to the set x1 
   we can take that new number 1 + 19 = 20 to create our desired sum 20.

**Dynamically build a matrix** 
Cool! now let us utilize the above four logics and start building from the base case. We are going to build a matrix `m`. We define:

- matrix `m` has `i+1` rows and `k + 1` columns.
- Each cell of the matrix has value `true` or `false`.
- m[i][s] returns true or false to indicate the answer to this question: "using the first `i` items in the array can we find a subset sum to `s`? " `m[i][s]`returns `true` for yes and `false` for no

(note the Wikipedia answer or most of the people build a function m(i,s) but I thought the matrix is an easy way to understand dynamic programming. It works well when we only have positive numbers in the set or array. However the function route is better because you don't have to deal with index out of range, match index of the array and sum to the matrix.....)

**Let us build the matrix using an example:**

```
X = {1,3,5,2,8}
k = 9
```

We are going to build the matrix row by row. We ultimately want to know the cell m[n][k] contain `true` or `false`.

***First Row:***
Logic 1. told us that the first row of the matrix should all be `false`.

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0| F F F F F F F F F F
1|
2|
3|
4|
5|
```

***Second Row and above:***
Then for the second row or above, we can use logic 2,3,4 to help us populate the matrix.

- logic 2 tells us that `m[i][s] = (X[i-1] == s)` rememebr m[i] is referring to the ith item in X which is X[i-1]
- logic 3 tells us that `m[i][s] = (m[i-1][s])` this is looking at the cell direclty above.
- logic 4 tells us that `m[i][s] = (m[i-1][s - X[i-1]])` this is looking at the row above and left of X[i-1] cells.

If any of these is `true` then `m[i][s]` is `true` otherwise `false`. so we can rewrite 2,3,4 into `m[i][s] = (m[i-1][s] || a[i-1] == s || m[i-1][s - a[i-1]])`

Use these above logics to populate the matrix `m`. In our example, it looks like this.

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0| F F F F F F F F F F
1| F T F F F F F F F F
2| F T F T T F F F F F 
3| F T F T T T T F T T
4| F T T T T T T T T T 
5| F T T T T T T T T T
```

***Now use the matrix to answer your question:***

look at `m[5][9]` which is the original question. using the first 5 items (which is all the items) can we find a subset sum to 9 (k)? and the answer is indicated by that cell which is `true`

Here is the Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SubSetSum {

    public static boolean subSetSum(int[] a, int k){

        if(a == null){
            return false;
        }

        //n items in the list
        int n = a.length; 
        //create matrix m
        boolean[][] m = new boolean[n + 1][k + 1]; //n + 1 to include 0, k + 1 to include 0 

        //set first row of matrix to false. This also prevent array index out of bounds: -1
        for(int s = 0; s <= k; s++){
            m[0][s] = false;
        }

        //populate matrix m
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            for(int s = 0; s <= k; s++){    
                if(s - a[i-1] >= 0){ //when it goes left we don't want it to go out of bounds. (logic 4)
                    m[i][s] = (m[i-1][s] || a[i-1] == s || m[i-1][s - a[i-1]]); 
                } else {
                    m[i][s] = (m[i-1][s] || a[i-1] == s);
                }       

            }
        }

        //print matrix
        print(m);

        return m[n][k];

    }

    private static void print(boolean[][] m){
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++){
                if(m[i][j]){
                    System.out.print("T");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("F");
                }           
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = {1,3,5,2,8};
        int k = 9;

        System.out.println(subSetSum(array,k));

    }
}
```

To build the matrix `m` takes O((n+1)(k+1)) which is O(nk). it seems like it should be polynomial but it is not! It's actually pseudo polynomial. Read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)

Again this only works if the input only contains positive numbers. You can easily tweak it to work with negative numbers tho. The matrix would still have n+1 rows but `B - A + 1` columns. Where `B` is the upperbound and `A` is the lowerbound ( +1 to include zero).The matrix would still be You would have to offset `s` with the lowerbound.

It is pretty hard to explain DP problem over text from start to end. But I hope this helps those out there that try to understand this problem.

Note that in the examples above the rows of the DP table are sorted. That does not have to be the case.

Here is a DP table for the case of the question, i.e. given a set of {5, 3, 11, 8, 2}. For brevity, I have omitted the false values.

```
┌─────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ (index) │  0   │  2   │  3   │  5   │  7   │  8   │  10  │  11  │  13  │  14  │  15  │  16  │
├─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│    0    │ true │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │
│    5    │ true │      │      │ true │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │      │
│    3    │ true │      │ true │ true │      │ true │      │      │      │      │      │      │
│    11   │ true │      │ true │ true │      │ true │      │ true │      │ true │      │ true │
│    8    │ true │      │ true │ true │      │ true │      │ true │ true │ true │      │ true │
│    2    │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │ true │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Below is an implementation in JavaScript which will output the target set {5, 11}:

```js
var subSetSum = function(input, sum) {

    let y = input.length;
    let x = sum;

    if(input.length === 0) return 0;

    let d = [];

    //fill the rows
    for (let i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
      d[i] = [];
      d[i][0] = true;
    }
    
    for (let j = 1; j <= y; j++) { //j row
      for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) { //i column
      let num = input[j-1];
        if(num === i) {
          d[j][i] = true;
        } else if(d[j-1][i]) {
          d[j][i] = true;
        } else if (d[j-1][i-num]) {
          d[j][i] = true;
        }
      }
    }
    
    //console.table(d); //uncomment to see the table
    if(!d[y][x]) return null;

    let searchedSet = [];
    for(let j=input.length, i=sum; j>0 && i != 0; j--) {
      if(input[j-1] !== i) {
        while(d[j-1][i]) { // go up
          j--;
        }
      }
      searchedSet.push(input[j-1]);
      i = i-input[j-1];
    }

    return searchedSet;
};

console.log('searched set:'+ JSON.stringify(subSetSum([5, 3, 11, 8, 2], 16)));
```

Comment: Good explanation, I never thought how to handle -ve values, That's from where I came looking for.

Comment: Amazing explanation, Thanks a ton.

Comment: This is the best explanation I've found for this problem. The logic is right but I think the matrix you made is wrong. Look at s = 2, x = {1,2,3}. {1,2,3} does contain a subset sum for 2, though the matrix says it doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand whether Im doing something wrong or this actually doesn't work properly: I'm trying a set of {2, 3, 5, 10, 20} and see if sum can be 11.
It returns false. Any hints as to what's wrong? I assume it's because subset value needs to be reused for it to get to the sum. How can this be adjusted to work? Thanks!

Comment: @ThatMarc the set does not contain any subset which adds up to 11.

Comment: If `s - a[i-1]` becomes negative for large element in the `a` array, the program would throw exception which you should handle.

Comment: Very clear explanation! Thanks a lot for this! :D

Answer (score 20):

Since it looks like all your numbers are positive, you can solve this using dynamic programming:

Start will a boolean array `possible` of size K+1 with the first value true, the rest false. The ith value will represent whether a subset sum of i is possible to achieve. For each number n in your set, loop through the `possible` array and if the ith value is true, then set the i+nth value to true as well.

At the end, if the kth value in `possible` is true, then you can form a subset sum of k. Problem solved in O(NK) time.

[Wikipedia's page on the subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) has a detailed explanation of this algorithm applied to sets of integers not guaranteed to be positive.

Comment: Is it possible that `i + n` may be greater than `K + 1`?

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest to read [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)'s algorithm. The algorithm exists there, see **Pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming solution** for the `O(P*n)` solution, The solution is not polynomial time, is polynomial in (p,n) but it's not polynomial in n+log P (size of input) and because `P` can be very large like 2^n, the solution P*n = (2^n)*n is not a polynomial time solution in general, but when p is bounded by some polynomial function of n is polynomial time algorithm.

This problem is NPC, but there is a `Pseudo polynomial time`algorithm for it, and belongs to [`weakly NP-Complete`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_NP-complete) problems, Also there are [`Strongly NP-Complete`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete) problems, which means, you can't find any `pseudo polynomial time` algorithm for them unless P=NP, and this problem is not in this range of problems, So somehow is easy.

I said this as simple as possible,but it's not an exact definition of a Strongly NP-Complete or Weakly NP-Complete problems.

For detail see [Garey and Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability%3a_A_Guide_to_the_Theory_of_NP-Completeness) chapter 4.

Answer (score 6):

It seems I am late to the party, here are my two cents. We will create a `boolean[] solution[n+1][k+1]` such that `solution[i][j]` is `true` if using first `i` items (index `0` to `i-1`) we can get sum `j` from the set; else `false`. We will return `solution[k][n]` finally:

We can deduce the following points:

1. if sum is zero then always a possible answer (empty set) for any number of elements. So all true.
2. if set is empty we cannot have any subset hence no way to get any K. So never a possible answer. All false.
3. if a subset X1 (subset of X without last element in X) has a subset-sum for k then X also has it which is X1. E.g. for X1={1,3,5} and k=8, if X1 has a subset-sum then X={1,3,5,7} also has a subset-sum
4. For i/p set X = {1,3,5,7,19} and k=20, if X wants to know possibility of subset-sum for 20 then it does if x1={1,3,5,7} can have a subset-sum of 20-19 i.e. 1. It applies only if k >= 19 i.e. last element in X.

Based on the above points we can easily write the algorithm as below.

```
public class SubSetSum {
    boolean[][] solution; 
    int[] input;
    int k;

    public SubSetSum(int[] input, int targetSum) {
        this.input = input;
        this.k = targetSum;
        this.solution = new boolean[input.length+1][k+1];
    }

    public boolean subsetSum() {
        int n = input.length;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {     //case 1
            solution[i][0] = true;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++) {    // case 2
            solution[0][j] = false;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {                  // n times
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {              // k times and time complexity O(n*k)
                if(solution[i-1][j]) {
                    solution[i][j] = solution[i-1][j];      // case 3
                    continue;
                }
                if(j >= input[i-1])  {                       // case 4
                    solution[i][j] = solution[i-1][j-input[i-1]];
                }
            }
        }
        return solution[n][k];
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing a simple test this does not work: Subset = {2, 3, 5, 10, 20}; Sum = 11; Result is false. I assume this is because for this example values in the subset should be used more than once. Is it possible to modify this example to work for the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no known algorithm for subset sum that runs in less than O(2^(n/2)), in the general case.

Comment: This is probably not the general case. See my answer.

Comment: -1: There is one that runs in the complexity the OP wants, so your answer is really not helpful and also irrelevant.

Comment: @ivlad Kinda harsh, since @DeadMG is technically correct. OP didn't state that the set of integers are always positive which my answer assumes.

Comment: @IVlad: The OP did not explicitly state any constraints, so what am I going to do but assume he wants a general-case solution?

Comment: @marcog - they don't really have to be positive. If the range is `[-t, t]` for example, you can use an array `possible[i + t] = true if we can obtain sum i and false otherwise`. Hash tables can also be used.

Comment: @DeadMG - the dynamic programming `O(nk)` solution is general.

Comment: @ivlad Actually, it will have to be possible[i + sum_of_negatives]. And this sum is dependant on the magnitude of the values so it changes the order of the solution to O(N(K+N.max_num)).

Comment: @marcog - true, but that's the worst case anyway, so I don't think it changes too much.

Comment: @DeadMG, Subset sum is pseudo polynomial NP problem, and there is a O(nK) solution for it, (see wiki), In all The order of each algorithm which solves this problem is related to `n` and `k` not just n, if `log(k)>>2^n` then the coding of number `k` is more complex than an answer you said.

Comment: @Saeed: No, you check the wiki. `This solution does not count as polynomial time in complexity theory because P − N is not polynomial in the size of the problem, which is the number of bits used to represent it. This algorithm is polynomial in the values of N and P, which are exponential in their numbers of bits.`. Whoops. @IVlad: Subset sum is an NP-complete problem. If you have a general-case polynomial-time solution, then congratulations, you solved P=NP.

Comment: @DeadMG, It's pseudo polynomial time NPC, It's not NPC-Strong problem (you should read some book like `Garey and Johnson` book to understand difference between NPC-Strong and Pseudo...), those are different things, I can't understand what do you want to say to me (If you want take care about `wiki` scroll down to see **Pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming solution**, and I downvoted you, because you didn't take care about `K`, in your `O(2^(n/2))` order, your suggested order is false in all.

Comment: @DeadMG, and what @lVald said, is not conclude p=NP, you forgot about `K`, the size of input is `n`, means `n` item and they can be coded with `n*log(n)` (or n) bit, but if `K` is very big, i.e K = 2^n, the solution @lVald suggested required (2^n)*n, there is no polynomial relation between input size and the running time of algorithm.

Comment: And I never said that it's polynomial time algorithm, I just said that It's Pseudo polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: Actually, shifting the array elements by `t` to make them non-negative does not create an equivalent problem.  How far do you shift the sum?

Answer (score 4):

```
void subsetSum (int arr[], int size, int target) {
  int i, j ;
  int **table ;
  table = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int*) * (size+1)) ;
  for ( i = 0 ; i <= size ; i ++ ) {
    table[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * (target+1)) ;
    table[i][0] = 1 ;
  }
  for ( j = 1 ; j <= target ; j ++ )
    table[0][j] = 0 ;
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= size ; i ++ ) {
    for ( j = 1 ; j <= target ; j ++ )
      table[i][j] = table[i-1][j] || (arr[i-1] <= j && table[i-1][j-arr[i-1]] ) ;
  } 
  if ( table[size][target] == 1 )
    printf ( "\ntarget sum found\n" ) ; 
  else printf ( "\nTarget sum do not found!\n" ) ;
  free (table) ;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation... please?

Comment: Let S[i, j] be defined as true iff there is a subset
of elements A[1 . . . i] that sums to j . Then
S[n, T ] is the solution to our problem.
In general:
S[i, j] = S[i − 1, j − A[i]] ∨ S[i − 1, j]
Initial conditions are S[i, 0] = True, and
S[0, j] = False, for j > 0.

Comment: Since you compute values in `table[i]` using only values in `table[i-1]`, you can save space by making its outer dimension just 2 instead of `size`, and indexing it with `i % 2` instead of `i`.  I.e. swap the "current" array every outer iteration.

Answer (score 1):

let M be the sum of all the elements. 
Note that K<=M

```
let m be a Boolean array [0...M]
set all elements of m to be False
m[0]=1
for all numbers in the set let a[i] be the ith number
    for j = M to a[i]
        m[j] = m[j] | m[j-a[i]];
```

Then simply test for m[k]

Comment: for initial it is correct to mark  `m[0]` as true but you should also mark `m[x]` to be true if x is in the array `[0....M]`

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean hasSubset(int arr[],int remSum,int lastElem){
    if(remSum==0) return true;
    else if(remSum!=0 && lastElem<0) return false;

    if(arr[lastElem]>remSum) return hasSubset(arr, remSum, lastElem-1);
    else return (hasSubset(arr, remSum, lastElem-1) ||hasSubset(arr, remSum-arr[lastElem], lastElem-1));
}
```

Consider i-th element. Either it will contribute for the subset sum or will not. if it contributes for the sum, then the "value of sum" is decreased by the value equal to the i-th element. If it does not contribute, then we need to search for the "value of sum" in the remaining elements.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are all great but don't really give the broadest overview of how something like this could work for both positive and negative numbers.

Given an ordered set of integers, Define two variables X and Y such that

X = sum of negative elements

Y = sum of positive elements

and operate on your initial set as if you were recursing through a binary tree by applying these rules in this order

1. If the rightmost element is equal to the sum you are trying to check
   for return true
2. Recurse left if doing so would not leave the empty
   set, drop the rightmost element from your sorted array
3. If there is one element left in your set and it is not the sum return false
4. Instead of recursing right, check the sum of all elements in the
   array q, if X <= B <= Y then return true, if not return false
5. If the left subtree or the right ‘recursion’ returned true then return true to the parent

The above answers are more detailed and accurate but for a very broad view of how this should play out draw a binary tree. What does the length of this suggest about the runtime?

Answer (score 1):

```
function subsetsum(a, n) {
    var r = [];
    for (var i = parseInt(a.map(function() { return 1 }).join(''), 2); i; i--) {
        var b = i.toString(2).split('').reverse().map(function(v, i) {
            return Number(v) * a[i]
        }).filter(Boolean);
        if (eval(b.join('+')) == n) r.push(b);
    }
    return r;
}

var a = [5, 3, 11, 8, 2];
var n = 16;
console.log(subsetsum(a, n)); // -> [[3, 11, 2], [5, 3, 8], [5, 11]]
```

Brute force-- forget sorting, try every combo, and the eval parser beats Array.reduce (and it works with negative numbers too).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive Solution with n^2 time complexity

```
public void solveSubsetSum(){
    int set[] = {2,6,6,4,5};
            int sum = 9;
            int n = set.length;

            // check for each element if it is a part of subset whose sum is equal to given sum
            for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
                if (isSubsetSum(set, sum, i, n)){
                    Log.d("isSubset:", "true") ;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("isSubset:", "false") ;
                }
                k=0; // to print time complexity pattern
            }
        }

private boolean isSubsetSum(int[] set, int sum, int i, int n) {

            for (int l=0;l<k; l++){
            System.out.print("*"); 
            // to print no of time is subset call for each element
        }
        k++;
        System.out.println();     
        if (sum == 0){
            return true;
        }

        if (i>=n){
            return false;
        }

        if (set[i] <= sum){ 
        // current element is less than required sum then we have to check if rest of the elements make a subset such that its sum is equal to the left sum(sum-current element)
            return isSubsetSum(set, sum-set[i], ++i, n);
        }
        else { //if current element is greater than required sum
            return isSubsetSum(set, sum, ++i, n);
        }
   }
```

Worst Case Complexity: O(n^2)

Best case : O(n) i.e; if first element makes a subset  whose sum is equal to given sum.

Correct me if i am wrong to calculate time complexity here.

Answer (score 0):

DP solution with one dimensional array(DP array processing order does matter here).

```
bool subsetsum_dp(vector<int>& v, int sum)
{
    int n = v.size();
    const int MAX_ELEMENT = 100;
    const int MAX_ELEMENT_VALUE = 1000;
    static int dp[MAX_ELEMENT*MAX_ELEMENT_VALUE + 1]; memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));

    dp[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = MAX_ELEMENT*MAX_ELEMENT_VALUE; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (j - v[i] < 0) continue;
            if (dp[j - v[i]]) dp[j] = 1; 
        }
    }

    return dp[sum] ? true : false;
}
```