# Looking for combinations that add up to 15 in a card of hands

Tags: java, algorithm

I am writing a program that deals with cards and a hand. A hand has 5 cards. I want to know whats a good algorithm for deciding which combination of cards add up to 15. Kings, Queens, Jacks, count as 10 and a Ace count as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to subset sums, which I recently answered here: [Subset Sum algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4355955/89806)

The only tweak you need to make is to keep track of which card was used to get from `possible[i]` to `possible[i+n]`. You can keep track of these using a second array let's call it `card_used` and then set `card_used[i+n]` to a reference/index of the card used to get from `i` to `i+n`. Then at the end, you can retrieve the list of cards used to get to the sum of 15 (assuming `possible[15]` is true) by backtracking through the list `card_used`.

Answer (score 0):

1) get the hand
2) loop thru the hand
2a) each iteration, add the value of the car to a running total.
2b) if you ever get to more than 15 you can exit this iteration