# Recursive function building

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion, backtracking

I'm trying to write a function that explores all possible combinations of numbers , given as an array , in hopes to find the minimal group of numbers that add up to a certain amount , which is passed as an argument.

Here's what I've been doing , which seems to be working for some but not all cases;

I choose a number, subtract it from the total sum , and pass the new sum to the function,with the limits of the array intact , which gives me the option to re-choose the number,
in the second call I pass the new sum,i.e, total sum minus current chosen number , but I downsize the array by one, which mean that I won't be choosing the same number again.

However , I've realized that I'm not covering all the choices, because in any case I'm assuming that any number is vital for the solution , but I don't know which arguments to pass in order to cover the third option , which is not choosing the number,meaning i'ts not subtracted from the sum , and downsizing the array.

You're help would be greatly appreciated , and btw , I'm writing in C.

```
    int howManyCoins(int*coins,int size,int sum)
{
    return howManyCoins_aux(coins,size,sum,size-1);
}

int howManyCoins_aux(int*coins,int size, int sum,int chosen)
{
    if (sum==0)return 1;
    if (sum<0)return 0;
    if (chosen==0) return 0;
    if (coins[chosen]>sum) return 0;
    int res1=0,res2=0,best_solution=0;
    for (int i=chosen;i>=0;i--)
    {
        res1+=howManyCoins_aux(coins,size,sum-coins[i],chosen);
        res2+=howManyCoins_aux(coins,size,sum-coins[i],chosen-1);
        if(!(res1+res2)) best_solution=0;
        else if (res1==0) best_solution=res2;
        else if (res2==0) best_solution=res1;
        else best_solution=res2>res1?res1:res2;
    }
    return best_solution;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some codes or pseudo code.

Comment: Got any code so far? The algorithm looks *almost* reasonable.

Comment: And the numbers can be negative as well, right ?

Comment: I'll post the code in a minute , and @cnicuter actually no , the array is all positive numbers, and sorted from minimal value to maximal.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this in the most obscure, unreadable, ineffective way possible? This whole mess of a function can easily be replaced by a simple for loop.

Comment: I know , this is for a homework , and I'm requested to use recursion , or rather backtracking, and this "mess of a function" was written by a beginner in computer science , so cut me some slack :)

Comment: @Lundin It can't be replaced with a simple for loop (unless you use a stack to simulate recursion), recursion is required because each coins can be chosen 0 or more times. Feel free to try coming up with a for loop. The function looks a lot cleaner than 1000s of other people's code I've seen, there's just some unneeded complexity.

Comment: @Dukeling All forms of recursion can be replaced by loops. In some rare cases, recursion is more elegant, in most cases it is unnecessary and ineffective.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not arguing that recursion can't be replaced with loops (`"unless you use a stack to simulate recursion"`), but I (and most coders, in my experience) **completely disagree** that `"in most cases (recursion) is unnecessary and ineffective"`. Using recursion for 'recursive problems' (as this one, and there are lots of these problems) is generally more elegant and readable. for-loops can be (slightly) more efficient, yes, but so is coding everything in machine code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your choices to: Choosing the coin and being able to re-choose the coin or not choosing the coin (recursion will cover all option)

Replace:

```
res1+=howManyCoins_aux(coins,size,sum-coins[i],chosen);
res2+=howManyCoins_aux(coins,size,sum-coins[i],chosen-1);
```

with

```
res1 = howManyCoins_aux(coins, size, sum-coins[i], chosen);
res2 = howManyCoins_aux(coins, size, sum, chosen-1);
```

*If you can only pick 1 of each coin:* (which is the [change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem))

```
res1 = howManyCoins_aux(coins, size, sum-coins[i], chosen-1);
res2 = howManyCoins_aux(coins, size, sum, chosen-1);
```

Your algorithm is somewhat unclear, and I think there's a lot of repetition. You can get rid of the for loop, and change your function to something like: (untested)

```
int howManyCoins_aux(int *coins, int size, int sum, int chosen, int pos)
{
  if (sum == 0) return chosen;
  if (sum < 0 || pos == size) return 9999999;
  int res1 = 9999999;
  if (coins[pos] >= sum)
    res1 = howManyCoins_aux(coins, size, sum-coins[pos], chosen+1, pos);
  int res2 = howManyCoins_aux(coins, size, sum, chosen, pos+1);
  return min(res1, res2);
}
```

That being said, recursion probably isn't the way to go (it will take very long, even on small datasets). Sounds like [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). There are a few options for solving it in the link.

Comment: Yeah I kinda got desperate and started experimenting with all kinds of stuff xD

Comment: Actually I'm obligated to use recursion(this is for homework).
I followed your advice, and ran a few test , and I tracked the function using call trees, it's doing what it's supposed to do , how ever , it seems that I've got the return values wrong at the end of the function, my current code returns true or false ( 0 or 1) and not the actual group size :/, should I just return the sum of the two results ? but that wouldn't be the minimal solution would it ?

Comment: The requirements are :
- the amount of coins should be the minimal amount needed to reach the sum.
- any coin may be chosen more than once.
On a side note : I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the arguments pos and chosen in your code

Comment: Ok, I just included that part for completeness. `pos` is the position in the array. `chosen` is the chosen number of coins.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , I'm starting to wrap my head around the whole concept , just one last thing , what's wrong with my logic here : (code in third answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all possible values, you can use a bit array. If your given array is short enough you can use an integer (or a long integer) as a bit array. 
Now, let a be your array, then for each index n:
  a[n] is in the combination if and only bit n of your bit array is set.

Comment: but how would my function calls look like ? , I'm having a hard time covering the third option

Comment: With my suggestion you can drop the recursion. If your bit array is an integer, use ++ to move to the next combinations. To chack if bit n is set in integer b, use 'if(b & (1 << n))'.

Comment: actually I'm writing this for an assignment , and I'm obligated to use recursion :) , but I appreciate your input , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a variant of the subset sum problem. Since you are only considering positive numbers, a dynamic programming approach like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356000/1115008) would probably work if you kept another data structure to keep track of the sets of numbers that sum to each possible value.