# subarray with give sum (not continuous)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I have array of numbers and I want to find a subarray with given sum, Ive googled a lot but all explanations were for case where subarray is continuous. What if I dont need it to be continuous? how can I find it?

Comment: usually, a subarray is "continuous", you might want to search for subsets sums

Comment: Then the order doesn't matter, and we're talking about the weakly NP-hard subset sum problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subset Sum algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for *subset sum* instead.  This is a weakly NP hard problem, meaning it's solvable for integers by a classical dynamic program with runtime proportional to the magnitude of the elements in the set. This is exponential time.