# Dynamic programming - find the formula

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am cluelessly trying to solve this problem:

> Let `arr` be an array of integers of length `n` (indexed from 1 to n).
>
> Let `M[s][i]` be a matrix containing boolean values of, if there exist a subset of first `i` numbers of the array arr (arr[1], arr[2], ..., arr[i], ...,  arr[n]), of which the sum is exactly `s`.
>
> Find the recursive formula for the value of `M[s][i]` based on `M[?][j]`, where j < i and `arr` contains `j`. You can assume that `M[s][0] = 0`.

How would I find this formula? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please tag which language you are using.

Comment: @GenWan Hey, it's Java.

Comment: After answering, I now see that this question already has an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple recurrence formula based on your definition of `M[s][i]` would be:

```
M[s][i] = M[s][i-1] || M[s-arr[i]][i-1]
```

**Explanation**

- If `arr[i]` is not included in the subset, `M[s][i]` is `true` if
  there exists a subset of first `i-1` elements that has the sum
  exactly equal to `s`.
- If `arr[i]` is included in the subset, then
  `M[s][i]` can only be `true` if there exists a subset of the first
  `i - 1` elements that has a subset exactly equal to `s - arr[i]`.

This problem is popularly called the **Subset sum problem**. It already has multiple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm)

Comment: Thanks! So just to double check if I understand it correctly, regarding the second option. So you basically divided the problem into two subproblems, the first problem is 1, ... , i-1 and the second problem is just for i?

Comment: Yes. Basically, two subproblems, one in which the sum does not contain `arr[i]` and the second in which the sum contains `arr[i]`.