# What is the pseudocode for this algorithm asked by GOOGLE

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, pseudocode

This problem was asked by Google.

Given a list of integers S and a target number k, write a function that returns a subset of S that adds up to k. If such a subset cannot be made, then return null.

Integers can appear more than once in the list. You may assume all numbers in the list are positive.

For example, given S = [12, 1, 61, 5, 9, 2] and k = 24, return [12, 9, 2, 1] since it sums up to 24.

Comment: This is the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subset Sum algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355955/subset-sum-algorithm)